# Kotlin - thermal printer Arabic text never printed

Tags: android, kotlin, printing, escpos

Am using [DantSu library](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android) to print receipts but Arabic text is never printed

here is my code

```
val printer = EscPosPrinter(
            deviceConnection,
            printerData.printerDpi,
            printerData.printerWidthMM,
            printerData.printerNbrCharactersPerLine,
            EscPosCharsetEncoding("windows-1252", 16)
        )
```

Comment: Are you sure the library supports non-latin characters?  This is probably better asked to the people who write that particular library, possibly by raising a github issue.  Given that the library uses L and R for alignment rather than End and Start, my guess would be RTL language support is never something they thought about.

Comment: Also, the library has an open issues in github that cyrillic doesn't work from 12 days ago.  Only supports latin would be my guess.

Comment: The CharsetEncoding specification is an EPSON specification and it may not be clear if it matches the printer you are trying to use. [ESC t](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32) Please check it. And even if it's equivalent to EPSON, the printer won't have the ability to print from right to left. At least it is said that EPSON printers do not have it. Make sure your printer has that feature as well as CharsetEncoding. A realistic solution would be to convert all the data to a Bitmap image and print it.

Comment: @GabeSechan \\ it's not about the direction .. it's about printing Arabic chars

Comment: if there is another library to print with Arabic chars please suggest it

Comment: @kunif \\ i searched alot and i think you are right .. the only solution now is to generate image from text ...... but it's not totally correct

Comment: You're explicitly using a Latin charset there (Windows-1252) - have you tried using one of the Arabic ones on here? https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=32 (16 is the ID of the charset, you'll need to change that)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [comment](https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android/issues/235#issuecomment-1003582248) on the issue on the library .. we found a solution but not totally correct

```
 private fun getBitmap(text: String): Bitmap? {
    val paint = Paint()
    paint.setTextSize(28f)
    val bounds = Rect()
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)
    val width: Int = bounds.width()
    val height: Int = bounds.height()
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width * 2, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    canvas.drawText(text, 20f, 20f, paint)
    return bitmap
}
```